# How to delete a | key, value| pair from a Hashie::Mash

Tags: ruby, hash

I was trying to delete a key from a Hashie::Mash object. the contents of the mash are:

```
mash.java
=> #<Hashie::Mash jre7-174="C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin" jre8_123="C:/java/stuff/bin">
```

I tried using the function from the [Hashie::Mash delete](http://rdoc.info/github/intridea/hashie/Hashie/Mash#delete-instance_method) but I would either get a result of `nil` that didn't change the contents of the mash, or I would get the error:

```
mash.delete(jre8_123)
NameError: undefined local variable or method `jre8_123' for main:Object
        from (irb):54
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby200-x64/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I know I'm using this function incorrectly, but from what I see in the documentation, its not working properly. What should I do to delete a |key, value| from a Hashie::Mash?

[Hashie::Mash rdoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/z/zerobearing-hashie-0.1.9/Hashie/Mash.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a symbol or string to call that delete method.  Look at the `Hashie::Mash#delete` [spec on GitHub](https://github.com/intridea/hashie/blob/master/spec/hashie/mash_spec.rb#L213).

```
mash.delete(:jre8_123)
```

Something like that.  Calling it like this:

```
mash.delete(jre8_123)
```

Is going to try to reference something called `jre8_123` before feeding its result into `mash.delete`.  It's failing because there's no variable or method named that.

Comment: Yessir, that's it. I wasn't calling it correctly. Its the `mash.delete(:jre8_123)`